# Migrating to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, shared-libraries

We have to migrate files to SharePoint along with previous versions. In my local system all versions are available in different folders (E.g. Folder 1 for all files with their Version 1, Folder 2 with all their files with version 2 and so on). We want to migrate all these files to SharePoint along with their versions.

I was looking for some option to migrate these folders one by one to Explorer view to make versioning in SharePoint but it seems I have to checkout for creating a every new version.

Is there any other way to migrate all the previous versions of files to SharePoint?

Comment: Disable having to have checkout and just move them. Then when moved enable the option again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, upload the files in the folder containing your oldest version. Then consecutively upload from the folders containing each higher version using [PowerShell to add them as new versions to previous files](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/28/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-upload-a-new-file-version-to-sharepoint/). This will only work if the files are named identically.